# Opentelemetry in grafana / prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I've successfully implemented an endpoint in C# to send OpenTelemetry messages. However, I now need guidance on configuring the remaining components of the system. Specifically, I believe I need to set up an OpenTelemetry collector to gather metrics, and subsequently, I'll configure Grafana and Prometheus to visualize and monitor this collected data.

Is my understanding accurate in that an OpenTelemetry collector will be responsible for fetching metrics, with Grafana or Prometheus serving as the tools for visualizing and analyzing this data?

Comment: Your understanding is a bit inaccurate: Grafana- visualisation, Prometheus - gathering(scraping) and storage, otel collector - translation of otel metrics into Prometheus metrics (so that Prometheus can scrape it).

Comment: Installation and configuration of those services is off topic on SO, but almost definitely on topic for [devops.se]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to think about a few things here.

OpenTelemetry SDKs in your application will need to be setup to send the signals somewhere, I'd advise the OpenTelemetry Collector.

You'll then need to think about where you're going to store those signals. SaaS vendors (most offer some kind of free tier), or self hosting it. From there, you'll configure the collector to send the traffic to the backend you choose.

Then you'll need to think about how you'll visualise those signals. For SaaS vendors, you'll likely be using their UI primarily. For OSS/Self-hosting, you'll likely be looking at either their UI, or something like Grafana (which although isn't OSS, it's free to use) which can connect to a lot of datasources.

It's worth thinking about the different signals and how you store them. Metrics data is likely better in a Time-Series datastore, Logs and Traces can go in generic NoSQL/Column-store databases, of more tailor storage solutions.